# RabbitMQ: Why is the default ha-sync-mode manual?

Tags: rabbitmq

I've setup a RabbitMQ cluster and I'm following the documentation on setting up mirrored queues ([Highly Available Queues](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html)). It says:

> Queues can be set to automatically synchronise by setting the
>   ha-sync-mode policy key to automatic. ha-sync-mode can also be set to
>   manual. If it is not set then manual is assumed.

Why is manual synchronization the default? What are some use cases for manual synchronization?

In the mean time, I've used:

`rabbitmqctl set_policy ha-all ".*" '{"ha-mode":"all", "ha-sync-mode": "automatic"}'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just read through the link provided, came across this clause, which may explain why 'manual' is the default, with important parts highlighted:

> Explicit synchronisation can be triggered in two ways: manually or automatically. *If a queue is set to automatically synchronise it will synchronise whenever a new slave joins - **becoming unresponsive** until it has done so.*

So, automatic synchronise will make the queue unresponsive for a period of time, which may not be good depends on the use case of the queue. And, the automatic sync happens whenever there are new slave joins. If there is a large number of slave joining, then the queue will be unresponsive for quite a period of time, unless the queue is rather empty or the network is very fast.